# Having troubles creating this object

Tags: java

I'm very new to java, and trying to grasp making an object with two different values.
I'm trying to create a Customer object called customer, with the initial values of 1 and cust1, and then display the customer object to the output with toString()

Thanks for any help in advance.

Here's what I have currently.

```
public class Customer {

private int id;
private String name;





public Customer(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    Customer customer = new Customer(1, "cust1");
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new object instance within a classes constructor — this will result in a `StackoverFlowException`.

```
public class Customer {

    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    public Customer(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

In a separate class you can simply create a new instance by using

```
Customer customer = new Customer(1, "Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no entry point to your program, which should look like this in your class

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 //objects created here
}
```

You also create a `Customer` object as a member of your `Customer` class which means every `Customer` object contains another.

You can't set `Customer` members like this

```
Customer customer = new Customer(); //you also don't have a no argument constructor
customer = 1; //how would it know where to put this 1?
customer = cust1; //same as above
```

it would be like this (if they were in the right place, as mentioned above)

```
Customer customer = new Customer(); //if using this method you will need a no argument constructor
customer.id = 1;
customer.name = cust1;
```

or like this

```
new Customer(1,"cust1");
```

**In Summary**

- You need an entry point
- You are creating `Customer` with a no argument constructor but you only have one constructor which has two arguments
- You are -for some reason- creating a `Customer` inside every `Customer`
- You are not setting members of your `Customer` object in the correct (or even in a valid) way

Comment: I have no entry point because this is a seperate class, I have a main class.  Should I put my Customer object in my constructor like so?                  I edited my main post.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating your `Customer` inside your `Customer` class (not for your purposes).  It should be created by another class or in your entry point method.

Comment: Where do you want to use a Customer object?  That is where you should create a Customer object.  Probably in your main class.

Comment: This lesson is on immutable classes, I'm not sure I really understand them, but that is what it is saying to do. It says to 1) Create a Customer object called customer with initial values of 1 and "Cust1" 
respectively.

2) Display the customer object to the screen using the toString() method.

3) Create a String object reference called name and assign to it the customer's name.

4) Assign the value "Bo Beep" to the object reference name.

5) Display the customer object to the screen using the toString() method.

Comment: It says to have a main class and a customer class

Comment: One of your biggest problems is that every time a `Customer` object is created, another `Customer` is created with it, then another, and another. That's like every baby being born is born already pregnant, you'll just get an endless supply of `Customer`s, and your constructor will never return.

Comment: So create your customer object in your main class, but since this lesson is on immutable classes, I suggest you also read up on what they are and how best to design them. I recommend you read this page to help you understand the difference between mutable and immutable classes: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-are-mutable-objects-and-immutable-objects/38  You might want to take a look at this to help you with the design:  http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29  It's a page  which gives guidelines on how to design an immutable class.

Comment: An example of an immutable class in Java is Integer. If you create an Integer I by doing Integer I = new Integer(3); it doesn't matter which of its methods you call, if you print I, it will still be 3. If, for example, you could change the value printed out using System.out.println(I); to say 4 by calling some method, it would be mutable, as you would have changed its data. Bearing this in mind, what do you think the result of part 5 should be?

Comment: It should be the exact same as printing the other one.

Comment: I'm wanting the output to be something like this,

       Customer{id=1, name=Cust1}
       Customer{id=1, name=Cust1}

Comment: Please don't change the code in your question if it changes the answer.  You've fixed most of the problems I mentioned but you're still creating unlimited `Customer` objects because every time one is created, it cases the creation of another, and so on.